# Google Map Polyline Arrays

Tags: google-maps

I am new at Google Map applications. I have read an article about Polyline Arrays (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineArrays). In the example, it created a dynamic arrays using Event Click. My question is, is it possible that i can create a polyline in an array variable not on a click event?

Here is the code from google documentation:

```
var poly;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.879535, -87.624333);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  }
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  poly.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
}

/**
 * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
 * @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
 */
function addLatLng(event) {

  var path = poly.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear
  path.push(event.latLng);

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });
}
```

I have made some of my own code:

```
<script>
        var line;
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
                zoom: 2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var path = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
                new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856)];

            line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

            line.setMap(map)
        }

        function addNewPoint(position) {
            var path = line.getPath();
            path.push(position);
        }

        ''''' I create a single variable for a new path.
        var NewPath = [new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)];
        addNewPoint(NewPath);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

And when i run it. It does not work. Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
var NewPath = [new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)];
addNewPoint(NewPath);
```

to this:

```
var NewPath = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892);
addNewPoint(NewPath);
```

So you only pass through a LatLng point, rather than an array containing one.  So it corresponds more closely to the example you gave,

```
path.push(event.latLng);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response duncan. I have change it. Im am trying to add new polyline using an array variable. The only example i got from google are it only add polyline using click event. Is it possible that i could add new polyline just using an array variable?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response duncan. I have change it. Im am trying to add new polyline using an array variable. The only example i got from google are it only add polyline using click event. Is it possible that i could add new polyline just using an array variable after it initialize? My goal is that i will get the Lat and Long of the polyline from my database SQLServer. And uses a timer setInterval from time to time to make it realtime. Thank you for any guide.

Comment: yes, you can add polylines not just in response to user clicks. To get it from the SQL server will require you providing info via a server-side page, which you could call via Ajax